# Check if url leads to a defined state in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use UI-Router and if the requested state doesn't exist in my config I want the app go to a certain state depending on whether the user is authenticated or not. Either 'home' or 'dashboard'.

I tried to use $urlRouterProvider.otherwise but the authenticated is not available there (in `app.config`). Then I tried in `app.run` to use 'stateChangeError' and 'stateNotFound' which interestingly have no effect at all here.

So my idea to work around this is to check if the state exists by using the URL - which I can get with $location.path(). But a `$state.get()` with this always delivers `null` because it expects the name of a state, not the URL.

**So how can I find out, based on what the user enters, whether there is an according state?**

Comment: show how you tried to set up `$stateChangeError` ... it should work fine for this

Comment: What do you mean by authenticated is not available there?